# How to pagination the nested-relationships?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I read the [django-rest-framework nested-relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) :

You can see the `tracks` in `AlbumSerializer`:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

The official website do not give a method to pagination the `tracks` in `AlbumSerializer`, if the tracks count is too large, how to realize the pagination for tracks?

---

**EDIT**

I want to pagination it by passing a page number to the API.

Comment: how did you want to paginate? by specific page parametr? after you open an detail view for `Album` what is your next action?

Comment: You need to handle that by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

[Django have some paginator classes that can help you build it on your own.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/)

If you want to build a pagination you could do it like this:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def viewPage(request, page):
    paginator = Paginator(data, 10) # 10 being how many objects per page you want, data being an array of tracks
    try:
        tracks = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        tracks = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        tracks = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)    
    return render(request, 'view_page.html', {
        'tracks': tracks,
    })
```

The data you need to give the Paginator() is the entire collection of tracks as an iterable.